# What is the probability of an ace-high flop containing 2-6?

Tags: probability

Draw 3 cards. The first card is an Ace.

What are the odds that one of the next 2 cards is a 2,3,4,5 or 6?

5*4 = 20 cards. Are the odds then 20/51 (chance of first card 2-6) * 20/50 (chance of second card 2-6 | first wasn't)? Or am I undercounting because of the chance both are 2-6? Do I need to do 1 - chance of neither?

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/104041) :)

Comment: You've been here nearly five years. You should be using MathJax by now.

Comment: Can you clarify a bit? By "one of the next two cards", do you mean AT LEAST one or EXACTLY one?

Comment: @IAAW At least one, which is why the multiplication has got to be wrong

Comment: $1 - p(R \cup S) = 1 - p(R) - p(S) + p(R \cap S).$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since, as said in the comments, you are looking for the probability that *at least* one of the two following cards will be a $2, 3, 4, 5,$ or $6$, we can calculate this in two ways.

The first way is direct, and we just add the probabilities of all possible cases. Let W denote a $2, 3, 4, 5,$ or $6$, and X denote any other card.

Case 1: A, W, X.

Since the A is given, there is a $20/51$ chance of drawing one of the W cards. But then, there are only 19 W cards left out of the 50 remaining, so there are 31 X cards left. Hence the probability is $(20/51)(31/50)$.

Case 2: A, X, W.

By similar reasoning, we will get $(31/51)(20/50)$.

Case 3: A, W, W.

Once you draw the first W card, there are only 19 left, so the probability is $(20/51)(19/50)$.

Your final probability will be the sum of the probabilities of each case: $(20/51)(31/50)+(31/51)(20/50)+(20/51)(19/50)$.

Alternatively, you can take 1 and subtract the probability of the A, X, X case: $1-(31/51)(30/50)$. Your results should be the same.

Answer (score 0):

Alright I figured it out

Miss first card, hit second:

$(31/51) (20/50) = 0.243$

Hit first card, miss second:

$(20/51) (31/50) = 0.243$

Hit both cards:

$(20/51) (19/50) = 0.149$

Overall: 63.5%

Comment: We posted our answers at the same time lol. You got it!

Comment: @IAAW You got me by 9 seconds :)


I think the subtraction method is best here anyways

Comment: Hey @Alec, mind accepting one of the answers so that this question isn't in the category of "no accepted answers"?

Comment: @IAAW I accepted yours